# Will the label (red,..) attribute gets lost after move files from Mac to WIndows and then move back

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems

Since Windows doesn't support label in file attributes, will this information be ripped off?

In addition, what happens if I upload a labelled file to the internet and then download it back? would the attributes go missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you do the moving, and whether you move it back by the same (/similar enough) method.  Here are some examples:

1. If you move it to a Windows file server (running on an NTFS volume) over the SMB protocol, the Mac-only metadata (labels and such) will be stored an an NTFS alternate data stream on the server; if you copy it back the same way, the metadata will be recovered and reattached.
2. If you move it to something like a FAT32 format keychain drive, it'll be stored as two files: a regular file with the file's data contents, and a second [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleDouble) file with "._" as a filename prefix, containing all the Mac-only metadata.  Note that if you moved the file to Windows using a method that encodes this way, and moved back by method #1, the metadata would be in the wrong format and would get lost; the same would happen if you reversed the order.
3. If you upload it with something like a web form, I'm pretty sure the metadata will not be sent at all.  Similarly, if you download something from a web site, it won't look for ._ files or alternate data streams, so even if the metadata is on the web server, it won't get downloaded.  (Unless you store it on the server in something like [MacBinary format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBinary)...)

Comment: 2 followup questions.does ._files go with the original files when moving them around folders inside a pc?

Comment: 1. What if move to a NTFS format keychain drive? What protocol does pc or mac use (if at all) for moving files to and from portable hard disk / USB drive. 2. How can I make a newline in this comments? Hit enter/return would simply publish it.

Comment: @colinfang the ._ files won't automatically stay with the main files on a PC; in fact they're likely to confuse PC people who'll then do random things like throw them out.  I'm not sure what'd happen with an NTFS drive, as OS X doesn't write to NTFS by default (there are ways to enable it, but I haven't tried).  Finally, I don't think there's a way to put a newline in a comment.